# How to substract a single value from column of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

i have one data frame suppose:

```
name age hb
ali  34  14
jex  16  13
aja  24  16
joy  23  12
```

i have a value say "5" that i want to substract from each member of column "hb"

new column could be:

```
hb
9
8
11
7
```

What is the best method to do this...

thanks and regards.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Simply subtract the scalar value from the `pandas.Series` , for numerical columns pandas would automatically broadcast the scalar value and subtract it from each element in the column. Example -

```
df['hb'] - 5 #Where `df` is your dataframe.
```

Demo -

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
  name  age  hb
0  ali   34  14
1  jex   16  13
2  aja   24  16
3  joy   23  12

In [44]: df['hb'] - 5
Out[44]:
0     9
1     8
2    11
3     7
Name: hb, dtype: int64
```

Comment: In Py3 Jupyter NB. This does work for me. I have to go the lamba route
Works............ir_df['Relative time'] = ir_df['Relative time'].apply(lambda x: x - 5) does not work .........
ir_df['Relative time']-5

Comment: How do we assign the new set of values to the 'hb' column in Py3 without getting the "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame." warning? Thanks

Comment: You do it by using `df.loc["hb"]` instead of `df["hb"]`

Comment: The question suggests that the "new column" should replace the existing column in the DataFrame rather than being a Series output.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using this:

```
df['hb'] - 5
```

you will get a new single column. But if you want to keep the rest then you have to use:

```
df['hb'] -= 5
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also do this using the pandas.apply function

`df.loc[:, "hb"] = df["hb"].apply(lambda x: x - 5)`

Answer (score 3):

If you want this subtraction to be saved in your DataFrame and avoid the old `SettingWithCopyWarning`, use `loc`:

```
df.loc["hb"] -= 5
```

Importantly, if you need to use multiple conditions for selecting a value range, put both into the `loc` call (chaining does not work for this):

```
df.loc[df.age==34,"hb"] -= 5
```

Comment: Handy answer - df.iloc[:,2] -= 5 also works for this.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df["hb"] - 5
```

`df["hb"]` will select `hb` column and subtract 5 from it

Answer (score 0):

[`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) lets you assign the new values directly to your existing column `hb`:

```
In [6]: df.eval("hb = hb - 5", inplace=True)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
  name  age  hb
0  ali   34   9
1  jex   16   8
2  aja   24  11
3  joy   23   7
```

Since `inplace=True` you don't need to assign it back to `df`.