# change data in data frame pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in python as below

```
columnA columnB
  10       15
  22       34
  44       77
```

i want to change columnA to read 1 less than the data it has example as below.

```
columnA  columnB
  9       15
 21       34
 43       77
```

That is 10 became 9, 22 became 21 and 44 became 43 in columnA.

Comment: Use `df['columnA'] -= 1` or in another notation ``df['columnA'] = df['columnA']  - 1``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to substract a single value from column of pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140496/how-to-substract-a-single-value-from-column-of-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

To reduce values by 1 in a pandas dataframe, here's one simple solution:

```
df['columnA'] = df['columnA'].apply(lambda x: x-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly subtract values in place:

```py
df.columnA -= 1
```